# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'INFOCUS_THEME\Inc\Menus' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to follow a WordPress tutorial by Imran Sayed - Codeytek Academy (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNtw4yxEydM&list=PLD8nQCAhR3tT3ehpyOpoYeUj3KHDEVK9h) to allow wordpress to build a menu and then inject into the html. I have followed the turorials 22, 23 and 24 (from the playlist) trying to use this in my own project.

I have copied the code and folder/file structure and added in the class, helpers, singletons and autoloaders. BUT everytime I try and run the code i get

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'INFOCUS_THEME\Inc\Menus' not found in /home/will/Local Sites/karenkeyinfocus/app/public/wp-content/themes/infocus/template-parts/header/nav.php on line 13
>
> Error: Class 'INFOCUS_THEME\Inc\Menus' not found in /home/will/Local Sites/karenkeyinfocus/app/public/wp-content/themes/infocus/template-parts/header/nav.php on line 13

I have changed the text domain from aquila to infocus as thats whats in my project in all the locations. BUT i am completly stuck and can't work out why my code is not running.

Think this is the code thats causing the problems as it can't find the class 'INFOCUS_THEME\Inc\Menus'

```
<?php
$menu_class = \INFOCUS_THEME\Inc\Menus::get_instance();
$header_menu_id = $menu_class->get_menu_id( 'infocus-header-menu' );
$header_menus = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $header_menu_id );
?>
```

I have uploaded it to my github account and post the link here, as I thought that is the best way.

https://github.com/wkey1980/infocus

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a variable as a class you must use 'new' to initiate the class.

```php
$menu_class = new \INFOCUS_THEME\Inc\Menus();
//and then you can do
$menu_instance = $menu_class->get_instance();
```